# Update replicates record and adds new

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, sql-update

I have a model, called 'Portfolio' and a nested model called 'Investment'

Here is the view for portfolio edit (abridged):

```
<table style="margin-bottom: 6px">                           
   <thead>                                                    
   <tr>                                                       
     <td>Ticker Symbol</td>                                   
     <td>Shares</td>                                          
     <td>Remove Investment</td>                               
   </tr>                                                      
   </thead>                                                   
   <%= f.fields_for :investments do |builder| %>              
       <%= render 'investments/table_form', f: builder  %>    
   <% end %>                                                  
</table>
```

And the partial ( investments/table_form )

```
<tr>
  <td><%= f.text_field :ticker, class: 'form-control' %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :quantity, class: 'form-control' %></td>
  <td><span style="padding-top:-20px;"><%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %><%= link_to 'remove', '#', class: 'remove_fields btn btn-danger' %></span></td>
</tr>
```

Creating new portfolios works, but when I edit a previous one it takes the previous investments and adds all the new investments. EG: original investments: A, B, C. Edit portfolio and add new investment D. Saves A, B, C, A, B, C, D as investments for portfolio.

Update action:

```
before_action :set_portfolio, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy, :update]

def update
  nickname = @portfolio.nickname
  if @portfolio.update_attributes(portfolio_params)
    redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: "The portfolio \"#{nickname}\" was successfully updated."
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

private
def set_portfolio
  @portfolio = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
end

def portfolio_params
    params.require(:portfolio).permit(:nickname, :management_fee,    investments_attributes: [:ticker, :quantity, '_destroy'])
end
```

portfolio.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
    $(this).closest('tr').hide()
    event.preventDefault()
```

When I click the link "Remove" it hides the investment as well as changes the value of the hidden field to 1, which is correct. But doesn't save it.

Portfolio Model (abridged):

```
has_many :investments
accepts_nested_attributes_for :investments, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['ticker'].blank? }
```

After I submit the edit form, the parameters:

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
"_method"=>"patch",
"authenticity_token"=>"GX4xeCdH9iNIViYb7oR+c9/1MqHVOM+2iceFlztqrfukblGkJBZgPRoYC5XNIyMK9b/o/tZIgnUBe/0qafXyvw==",
"portfolio"=>{"nickname"=>"Wassef",
"management_fee"=>"1.0",
"id"=>"2",
"investments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"ticker"=>"WABIX",
"quantity"=>"1000",
"_destroy"=>"false",
"id"=>"6"},
"1"=>{"ticker"=>"WABIX",
"quantity"=>"1000",
"_destroy"=>"1",
"id"=>"7"},
"2"=>{"ticker"=>"NBQAX",
"quantity"=>"1000",
"_destroy"=>"1",
"id"=>"8"},
"3"=>{"ticker"=>"WABIX",
"quantity"=>"1000",
"_destroy"=>"false",
"id"=>"49"}}},
"commit"=>"Update Portfolio",
"id"=>"2"}
```

ID 7 and 8 should be deleted, but they are not.

Comment: About update - can you add hidden field with id of portfolio before the other fields and tell us what will happend? (  `<td><%= f.text_field :id, class: 'hidden' %></td>` ) I think this might cause some issues.

Comment: where would I put this? in the partial or the `thead`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was in the `portfolio_params`. I needed `:id` in it. Changed it to:

```
def portfolio_params
  params.require(:portfolio).permit(:nickname, :management_fee,    investments_attributes: [:id, :ticker, :quantity, '_destroy'])
end
```

And it works.